# ungroup multiple form input in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone help me how to properly ungroup this data in laravel using collection class (or helper)?

```
{
    "title": [
        "TITLE 1",
        "TITLE 2",
        "TITLE 3",
        "TITLE 4",
        "TITLE 5"
    ],
    "description": [
        "DESCRIPTION 1",
        "DESCRIPTION 2",
        "DESCRIPTION 3",
        "DESCRIPTION 4",
        "DESCRIPTION 5"
    ]
}
```

into:

```
{
    ['title' => 'TITLE 1', 'description' => 'DESCRIPTION 1'],
    ['title' => 'TITLE 2', 'description' => 'DESCRIPTION 2'],
    ['title' => 'TITLE 3', 'description' => 'DESCRIPTION 3'],
    ['title' => 'TITLE 4', 'description' => 'DESCRIPTION 4'],
    ['title' => 'TITLE 5', 'description' => 'DESCRIPTION 5'],
}
```

Im saving a one to many relationship and I like to dynamically create form input by creating with these appended on the form

```
{{ Form::text('title[]') }}
{{ Form::text('description[]') }}
```

Or any better idea to properly create a multiple posts at once in a single page?

Comment: Just name your form fields appropriately: `post[0].title, post[0].description, post[1].title, post[1].description`

Comment: Thanks Steve, I really thought of that and I guess it was really more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use collections for this, but like most things in programming, there are an infinite number of ways to do anything. These examples all assume there will always be an equal number of titles and descriptions.

**Laravel Collections**

```
$finished = collect($data['title'])->map(
    function($item, $key) use ($data) {
        return [
            'title' => $item, 
            'description' => $data['description'][$key]
        ];
    }
);
```

**Native Array Functions**

```
$finished = array_map(function($item, $key) use ($data) {
    return [
        'title' => $item, 
        'description' => $data['description'][$key]
    ];
}, $data['title'], array_keys($data['title']));
```

**Simple For Loop**

```
$finished = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($data['title']); $i++)
{
    $finished[] = [
        'title' => $data['title'][$i],
        'description' => $data['description'][$i]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for these. I was trying to find an elegant way for this code. I thought there is already ready-made function provided by the laravel as this was simply the opposite of groupBy function of a Collection class. I consider using the map method you used above. Thanks.